# display html inside html

Tags: html

I have an html page and i want tou include inside it another html page wich have lots of links. I was able to make it happen with an iframe, but i want the page inside the iframe to have the same color properties for the text and the links as the original page and i don't want a scrollbar, i just want to fully show the links page (around 700 lines of links), there is a limitation and i can only see 38 lines of links without scrollbar.

Is there any way to do it without iframe? or can i adjust anything else to the iframe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<style>
div.frame{
    width:50%;
    height:50%;
    border:solid #000 1px;
}
</style>

<div class="frame"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('document').ready(function(){
    $('div.frame').load('/links/links1.html');
});
</script>
```

just link  a jquery library to make it work:) hope this helps..

Comment: You won't have to tweak the CSS at all. It will pick the styles from the parent page and apply to the content it loads.

Answer (score 3):

Look at [jQuery .load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) to load a div with that requested HTML.

Comment: the iframe code is this: <iframe src="/links/links1.html" frameborder="0" sandbox="allow-same-origin" </iframe> and it is inside a valid html file. How should i change the code or the html file to be able to use the jQuery?

Comment: Vainglory07 provided the proper implementation in his answer.